# how to use pattern in split() of String in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have input of the format

```
    "MG3 4F W 123 TO GH2 2F E 345" 
    or
    "MG3 4F W 123 To GH2 2F E 345"
    or
    "MG3 4F W 123 tO GH2 2F E 345"
    or
    "MG3 4F W 123 to GH2 2F E 345"
```

i have to split this kind of string based on "TO".Below is the code which i tried to used to split it using pattern but it gives compilation error can you please help me ???

```
    public static final String DIVIDER_PATTERN = "{tT}{oO}";
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(DIVIDER_PATTERN);
        String hello = "Hello to World TO this tO test To how";
        String array[] = hello.split(DIVIDER_PATTERN);
        System.out.println(array[0]);
     }
```

Comment: Sorry for adding wrong pattern.Its [tT][oO]

Comment: All we need to modify the above code a little 
`public static void main (String args[])
         {
          Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[tT][oO]");
          String hello = "Hello to World TO this tO test To how";
          String array[] = pt.split(hello);
          for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++)
           System.out.println(array[i]);
         }`
What need to do is to first define the pattern and then using it split the string.

Answer (score 3):

Change `{tT}{oO}` to `[tT][oO]`.

It is square brackets that denote [character classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum), whereas curly braces are used for something else entirely (the repetition operator).

Comment: thnks aix..i just saw what i had accidentally posted in code section.